# How to return error status and validation errors from this Spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an action method defined like this in one of my controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Post create(@Valid Post post, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // how to return an error status + error messages from here?
    } else {
        postRepository.persist(post);
        return post;
    }
}
```

When the post is persisted successfully, I return the post back to the client. But when it has validation errors, I want to return an Error status code as well as all the validation error messages back to the client.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you designing API or handling Form?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sine you are desigining a REST api, you need to create your own Pojo (aka. Resource) which will represent odd behaviour or validation errors, as stated by horaceman. I will show you how we do it in our application.

Since we are using JSON as a data representation, we wish to receive following information if unexpected exception occurs.

```
{ "status" : "EXCEPTION", "exceptionName" : "MyCustomException", "exceptionMsg" : "ex.unsupportedOperation" }
```

This is an example of course. Nice solution about it is that we can treat `exceptionMsg` as a key in our frontend to display proper `i18n` message or display it to the user as it is (in this case we use more descriptive messages).

Now, when everything is OK we do something like this:

```
{ "status" : "OK", "data" : {(...)} }
```

`Data` element is optional. We can send whatever we need to notify the frontend, or skip it totally.

The last scenario would be yours - validation errors. In this case we usually send following content:

```
{ "status" : "VALIDATION_FAILED", "errors" : [ "fieldName" : "username", "errorCode" : "validation.requiredField", "errorMsg" : "Username is required."] }
```

So clearly API clients will receive information that validation has failed and in proper fields - exact details about what went wrong. Of course `errors` is an array (or `List`), so we always provide as many details as necessary.

**How I do it?**
Easy, those objects are simple POJOS which are translated to JSON using Jackson. This gives me unlimited possibilities of JSON representation. What I do, is I'm preparing POJO representing Validation errors (for instance) and add it as a `Model` to my `ModelAndView` instance. Then I just rely on Spring to do proper JSON marshaling.

In your case you have `@ResponseBody` annotation with your `Post` instance, so as far as I know you won't be able to do that. Your setup is saying "Well, no matter what happens - always return an instance of Post". What you should do, is to replace it with simple `ModelAndView`, supply it with proper `Model` based on validation and return it to the client API.

Answer (score 7):

For @ResponseBody I would remove BindigResult from the method signature and let the BindException be thrown. I would then use an @ExceptionHandler method to return an object that contains the errors as Likacz described.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Post create(@Valid Post post) {
    postRepository.persist(post);
    return post;
}

@ExceptionHandler
public ValidationErrors handleException(BindException ex) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Please note that if you want to return `ValidationErrors` in the response body, the `handleException` method will need `@ResponseBody`.

Answer (score 4):

i think you want to make an ajax call in your controller. you return a post object in the method, so it is impossible to return another object(such as error message with code). how about return an ExecutionResult instead?

```
ExecutionResult{
 private int statusCode;
 private String message;
 private Object yourPost;
 //get and set methods here...
}
```