# Returning errors from controller back to view in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

In Spring MVC I have the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="adminUsers", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView listAdminUsers(Person newPerson,  HttpServletResponse response)  throws Exception {
Person person = personService.findPerson(newPerson.getUsername());
if (person == null) {
    // Set errorText = "Invalid Person";
    // redisplay view
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("adminUsersList");
    return mav;
} else {
    Roles roles = new Roles();
    roles.setPersonCode(person.getPersonCode());
    roles.setRoleType("ADMN");
    rolesMapper.insert(roles);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/adminUsers.html");
} 
}
```

With the view:

```
    <form:form method="post" action="${action}" commandName="person" >
    <form:label path="username">Add new administrator:</form:label>
    <form:input path="username" size="20"/>
    <form:errors path="username" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Changes"/> </form:form>
```

How would I return an error back to the view, so it is displayed by the `<form:errors path="username" />` tag?

This is simlar to [How to return error status and validation errors from this Spring MVC controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337824/how-to-return-error-status-and-validation-errors-from-this-spring-mvc-controller) except I'm returning a webpage, not a REST object, so the answers there don't apply.

I don't want to use `Validator` because the above calls the database, it's not simply a check for if username is not empty etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `BindingResult` to your method signature.  From there, `bindingResult.rejectValue("username", "username.notvalid", "Username is not valid");`

Comment: That throws: `org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'Invalid username.person.username'` . 

 My method is now: `public ModelAndView listAdminUsers(Person newPerson,  BindingResult result, HttpServletResponse response)  throws Exception` 
and the reject line is 
`result.rejectValue("username","Invalid username");`

Comment: Sorry about the incorrect signature for rejectValue.  Glad to hear you worked it out.  I've updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

BrandonV had it.  My Controller now looks like:

```
  // Create a new item
@RequestMapping(value="adminUsers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView listAdminUsers(Person newPerson,  BindingResult result, HttpServletResponse response)  throws Exception {
    Person person = personService.findPerson(newPerson.getUsername());
    if (person == null) {
        result.rejectValue("username","username.notvalid","Username doesn't exist");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("adminUsersList");  //This is ugly, it's copy & pasted from above
        mav.addObject("adminUsersList", adminService.findAllAdminUsers()); //Ugly...
        return mav;
    } else {
        Roles roles = new Roles();
        roles.setPersonCode(person.getPersonCode());
        roles.setRoleType("ADMN");
        rolesMapper.insert(roles);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/adminUsers.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your method logic:

> if (result.hasErrors){
>   return "";
>   } else {
>   creating your person object logic goes here!
>   }